# AndroidStudio select mobile number in editor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

in AndroidStudio how can i select all phone numbers like with `989468798787` which that started with `98` and with `12` character length?

this regex can't select correctly:

```
(((\+?98)?|0) ?9[\d ]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `[98]\\d{11}`. It will allow only those numbers which are beginning with `9` or `8` and having total length of 12 digits.
Here is a sample running code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class Main 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[98]\\d{11}"); 
        Matcher m = p.matcher("895123456865"); 
        boolean b = m.matches();
        System.out.print(b);
   }
}
// OUTPUT: true
```

Comment: i think you don't read my question carefully, i want to use this regex to search phone numbers on AndroidSutdio `editor` which i opened file , not programing in java

Comment: okay, I missed the editor part completely. So you needed only the regex which I posted?